# How do I run xkbcom on Ubuntu GNOME startup?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, 15.04, xkb

Using [`xkbcomp -xkb`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xkbcomp.1.html) I have generated a keyboard description and stored it in my home directory - `~/.keyboard-map`.

I can "use" this keyboard description by executing the following command:

```
xkbcomp ~/.keyboard-map $DISPLAY
```

This works fine, however, when I reboot my system, the description is no longer applied - each time I login, I have to enter that command again, manually.

**How can I run this command on start-up, automatically?** I am using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open your text editor of choice and paste this into it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keyboard
GenericName=A descriptive name here
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=xkbcomp ~/.keyboard-map $DISPLAY
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Save this as `keyboard.desktop` into  ~/.config/autostart and make it executable

```
sudo chmod +X ~/.config/autostart/keyboard.desktop
```

Reboot and it will start at boot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not work for me.

Comment: I even tried making `keyboard.sh` executable (i.e. `chmod u+x ~/keyboard.sh`) and still nothing.

Comment: Try changing the `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true` in keyboard.desktop

Comment: I will do that now, two seconds. Cheers.

Comment: Still nothing. I am not familiar with the `autostart` directory and `.desktop` files but I was expecting a terminal window to open but it did not - is this relevant?

Comment: Did you save the `keyboard.desktop` to the correct folder ? Open a file browser in /home and press Ctrl+H to show hidden files  and find .config and then autostart to make sure they are there and keyboard .desktop is in it

Comment: Yes I think a terminal should of opened

Comment: I am sure it is in the correct folder.

Comment: Make sure the `keyboard.sh` is in your /home then right click it and choose properties and then the permissions tab and make sure Execute is checked

Comment: I change the answer, based on something i read this simpler way will work

Comment: I had the same issue with keyboard.desktop file not working, the solution was to place the command into ~/.config/openbox/autostart So in my case I have "openbox" session started and in your case it might be something similar.